# :id => "info" error rails wicked forms when retrieving params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

I'm new to wicked form and I was following the [railcast episode on wicked forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?autoplay=true) but I keep receiving this error "Couldn't find Company with 'id'=info". So I know that the problem is clearly in my controllers somewhere. I know it's something super simple that I'm just racking my brain on so I know you guys will be a giant help. Here is the code, any and all help appreciated!

Code for companies Controller:

```
def create
@company = Company.new(company_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @company.save
    @object = @company.id
    format.html { redirect_to(company_steps_path(@company)) }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
```

Code for company_steps Controller:

```
class CompanyStepsController < ApplicationController


include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :info, :address, :quote

  def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    render_wizard
  end
  def update
    @company = Company.where(id: params[:id])
    @company.attributes = params[:company]
    render_wizard @company
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use #find and the record is not found ActiveRecord raise a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with a message like "Couldn't find Company with id='somevalue'".

I assume your id column is of type integer and you pass a string.

In your #show method params[:id] == 'info'.

Check your link_to, redirect_to and routes.

At some point you generate this url http://localhost:3000/company_steps/info (probably in a view).

You do a GET request on it, which match GET "/company_steps/:id" company_steps#show.

The method #show is call in the controller CompanyStepsController with params[:id] == 'info'.

As we see previously you get a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception because ActiveRecord can't find the record with a id 'info'.

The error is raise in your controller, but the problem is probably in your views or in a redirect. You need a id and you pass a string.

## EDIT: as discussed in comments

Ok params[:id] == 'info' is generated by wicked.
They use id to control the flow of steps.
You need to use nested routes to have rails generate something like params[:company_id].

resources :companies do
    resources :steps, controller: 'companies/steps'
end

So rake routes should give you:
/companies/:company_id/steps/:id

in the controller
params[:company_id] == 42
params[:id] == 'info'

https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step

Comment: I'm trying to pass an object upon save to a new controller I created for Wicked Form, idea being I can break a larger form into 3 steps. In my Company Controller, I am passing or better yet trying to pass the object (@company) to the new controller which is the Company_Steps_Path. In the new path I am trying to retrieve that object by pulling it through it's :id. :id in rails is always an integer, in my routes it contains the following **resources :companies
  resources :company_steps**

Comment: Ok params[:id] == 'info' is generated by wicked.
They use id to control the flow of steps.
You need to use nested routes to have rails generate something like params[:company_id].

resources :companies do
    resources :steps, controller: 'companies/steps'
end

So rake routes should give you:
/companies/:company_id/steps/:id

In the controller
params[:company_id] == 42
params[:id] == 'info'

https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step

Comment: Ok, probably should have paid more attention to the github page. They have a link walking through my exact scenario here [Building Partial Objects Step by Step](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step) please edit your answer to read what we've discussed and I'll mark it as correct.